# Opensource - Components Reusable

Tags: components

1. A reusable component may require modifications to adapt it.

   2. An opensource component is a reusable component.

Right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Then you have to pay attention the Open Source component to see what are your requirements.

You should ask these questions on http://opensource.stackoverflow.com.